# Mixing Forms and Windows authentication in .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, iis

This has been possible up to .Net4.0 and IIS 7.5.

The general idea is that you enable anonymous and forms authentication for your intranet site and in a subdirectory you enable windows authentication together with forms authentication and turn off anonymous. By disabling the forms 401 => 302 redirection with some custom code you will be able to get a hold of the users username and domain.

If you google for a solution all roads seem to lead to this blog/solution:
http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/

However when upgrading to .net 4.5 and IIS8 it breaks, Always forcing a 302 redirect to the login page and no means of getting a hold of the usernamen.

Has anyone solved this yet?

Answer (score 8):

I made a MVC 5 solution that makes it look like an external provider, the full source code here:

https://github.com/MohammadYounes/MVC5-MixedAuth

I didn't have the chance to test it on IIS 8, try it and let me know.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: As I understand the user has to enter their windows username in order to authenticate with Windows, is this right? You can't do it automatically?

Comment: @Tuco nope, it's auto login.

Comment: What IIS setting should be used?

Comment: @AkmalSalikhov see https://github.com/MohammadYounes/Owin-MixedAuth#iis

Answer (score 0):

Per my testing of this setup (.NET 4.5 / IIS 7.5 with both windows authentication and forms authentication enabled), the following condition

`(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)`

is `true` (after the user successfully authenticates via Windows auth), which can be theoretically used to determine a way around this issue. You did not post any code, so I can't say for sure how you would solve your problem. Are you creating a custom forms authentication ticket?

It seems that Windows authentication now trumps the Forms authentication, and `Request.IsAuthenticated == true` even before the code creates the Forms authentication ticket! Very annoying, this caused problems for one of my customers when they decided to install .NET 4.5, after they had been working fine for several years by mixing both Windows and forms auth. For now (until a patch is ready, and customer has time to test and deploy it) the solution was to remove .NET 4.5 and re-install 4.0. If they really think they need 4.5 for something, they will use a diff machine.

For example, you could create a custom identity class with your own version of `bool IsAuthenticated` instead of relying solely on `Request.IsAuthenticated` (again, you didn't post code so I can only assume this is what you are doing).  Then the solution involves checking whether the forms authentication ticket exists in the case where these two factors are `true`:

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated && (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)`

You can no longer rely solely on `Request.IsAuthenticated` because, technically, the request was authenticated when the user authenticated via Windows auth. (Whereas before, when mixing windows auth and forms auth, `Request.IsAuthenticated` was not `true` until the forms authentication ticket was created.)

Comment: Interesting. I am experiencing the opposit. Forms auth trumps win auth, and all requests to a page under win auth is immediately redirected to the forms login page.
However, my setup is an IIS8, not 7.5.

I was using the IIS win auth to retrieve the users AD username and domain and manually do a forms login. That way I could offer both single sign on and manual logins with a form.

Comment: I also do that for SSO. If I could configure the system to avoid setting `Request.IsAuthenticated=true` after windows auth (and before forms auth) I could avoid doing a patch (altering all code that checks `Request.IsAuthenticated` to use a roll-my-own property instead.) Would you be willing to post your web.config please? I see same behavior in server 2012/iis8 (request is considered authenticated after windows auth success, but before forms auth so  'windows' is the primary auth method from asp.net's point of view instead of forms.. but no luck with config options yet). Thanks for the info.